# Pentaho Data Integration 9 get rid of useless log lines

Tags: logging, pentaho-data-integration

I set up a paralel instalation of PDI 9 next to PDI 7. Both have there own properties and configurtaion (equal by now).

I created a very simple job + transformation just to check the installation. .kjb and .ktr just write a log comment with ${Internal.Kettle.Version} ${Internal.Kettle.Build.Date} and the transformation makes a small database call.
This works on PDI7 as well as on PDI9. On my Windows Desktop with Spoon GUI and on Linux Server with kitchen and pan.

But executed with kitchen on pdi 9 (productive) I get 185 log lines instead of the expected 38 lines with kitchen on PDI7. Executed with Spoon (PDI9) on Windows it also writes only expected lines.

Looks like it is not from PDI itself (not effected by loglevel) but from integrated libraries.
There is a lot of useless stuff from karaf (maybe other to).

How do I get rid of this? Log files get unreadable:-(
Any idea?

Comment: What happens when you change the logging level?

Comment: Nothing. Looks like this output is generated by libs and not by PDI itself.

Comment: Currently running into this same problem now, will update if I manage to find a solution.